# Get grayscale image from CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: ios, image, ocr, tesseract, grayscale

I'm developing an application to detect text from an image. I use `AVCaptureSession` for getting sample buffer images. Also I use Tesseract lib for recognition. But it gets poor quality detection. I use following code to get image from `CMSampleBufferRef`. Can anyone edit that code to get grayscale image as output. I heard grayscale image input will be better for recognition in Tesseract.

```
// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
- (UIImage *)imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                             bytesPerRow, colorSpace,   kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to do it yourself? I mean, yes, it's definitely possible.

Comment: @WilShipley This code i got from Apple's Dev Site. Actually i have code to convert UIImage to grayscale image. But Im looking for avoid that code and get grayscale image from this method itself. Also Im getting a rotated image as output from this code. Please help me to fix that also.